# making a frequency polygon with the y axis as a percentage of the max

Tags: r, ggplot2, binning

given the code

```
set.seed(1234)
dat <- data.frame(cond = factor(rep(c("A","B"), each=200)), 
                  rating = c(rnorm(200),rnorm(200, mean=.8)))
head(dat)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=rating)) + geom_freqpoly()
```

I need to change the y-axis to percentage of the maximum count.  What is the best approach?

Further edited:  I am not looking for a way to show the percentage of the total data points, but to set the maximum count as 100%, and show all the other bins as a percentage of that max.  So the y axis would run from 1-100, with the top of the peak at 100.

Comment: `ggplot(dat, aes(x=rating, y = stat(density))) + geom_freqpoly()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was a bit confused as to what you were asking initially, but now I understand: you want to represent the y-axis "normalized" to `..count..`, where your highest point is equal to 1.0 (maximum value), and all other points are equal `value / maximum value`.

For that, this should work:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=rating, y=..count../max(count))) + geom_freqpoly()
```

[image]

If you want to change the values to be from 0 to 100 (instead of 0 to 1), then just multiply by 100:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=rating, y=(..count../max(count))*100)) + geom_freqpoly()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I am not looking for a fraction of total data points, but percent of mode - i.e. setting the top of the peak as 100.